# asp.net multiple user calculation error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Apologies if this has been asked/solved before. I've done a fair bit of searching but can't seem to find a direct answer to my problem.
I'm still very new to asp/vb coding.

I've created a complex calculator in asp.net using vb.net.
The user fills out a few text boxes with information then clicks the calculate button. The program then accesses an sql 2014 server to collect more information based on information the user has entered, then uses the information to run a few very complex calculations (I don't completely understand the calculations behind it).

It all works fine and is able to give the correct answer, the problem I've found is if there is more than one user accessing the site and they happen to click the calculate button within the same time, whoever clicked the calculate button first gets an error whilst the person who clicked second gets an answer.

I'm not sure if this is to do with how it accesses the sql database for information or if the information is somehow being overridden.

I was hoping this would be a common problem, but can't seem to find anything on it, at least I may not be asking the right question when searching.

Unfortunately for security reasons I'm not able to post any code for it (I'll see if I can get permission) but am hoping that someone has come across something similar and knows a work around. Maybe to have the site wait until the first round of calculations is complete before initiating the second round?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please make sure that you should not use any shared variable in calculation because shared variables are common for all users. Also check for application variables.

Comment: Hi @PiyushKhatri,

Thanks for the reply, I've looked over the code and there are no Shared variables; there are however a fair few Public variables, would this have the same effect as a shared?

Cheers,

Comment: Yes. Please change your public variables to private.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, I'll give that a go. The only problem is that there are few subs that use the same variable a few times in when running, If I change them to private I get this error:

" 'ArcX' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Is there a way around this or would I have to use viewstate for those that are referenced multiple times?

Comment: I can understand, but if those public variable's value changed at one place, then after everywhere that variable's value will be new even if you are in middle of some processing.

Comment: @PiyushKhatri, Okay it runs perfectly with the variables defines as Private and within only one module. I had multiple modules to help separate code in a an easier to view format; are there any articles on ASP.net format/helping with how to split code up or is it going to have to be in one module? Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you should not use any shared variable in calculation because shared variables are common for all users. Also check for application variables.

I can understand, but if those public variable's value changed at one place, then after everywhere that variable's value will be new even if you are in middle of some processing.